# resize image of a 4-dimensional array in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lasagne

I'm working with `Python 3`.

I have a variable data from type `unit8` and size `(60000, 1, 28, 28)`, what means, that I have `60000` images with 1 channel and a size of `28x28` pixels.
Now I like to resize the images to `60x60` pixels, so that I get a size of `(60000, 1, 60, 60)`

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4):

Following solution worked for me. After list comprehension the list will be stacked back to a batch with numpy:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

target_shape = (60, 60)

def _resize_image(image, target):
   return cv2.resize(image, dsize=(target[0], target[1]), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

image = [_resize_image(image=i, target=target_shape) for i in data]
data_batch = np.stack(image, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `opencv` you can `resize` using,

```
img = pics[i][0]
new_img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=2, fy=2, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
```

Now your `i`th image is resized by factor 2 from both `x` and `y` directions (Here `pics` is the `numpy` array with your `(60000, 1, 28, 28)` images). If you don't use `opencv`, you can install it (Search google)

If not you can use `PIL` package. You can install it using,

```
pip install Pillow
```

And use the following code to resize.

```
from PIL import Image
img = pics[i][0]
im = Image.fromarray(np.rollaxis(img, 0,3))
new_im = im.resize((new_x, new_y), Image.BICUBIC)
```

You can use a `for loop` to put these images to an array of `(60000, 1, x ,y)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Keras, use this within the Keras model setup

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: tf.image.resize_images(x,[66,200]), input_shape=(160,320,3)))
```